# Scala: const method in covariant class

Tags: scala

Suppose I want to implement some sort of immutable set in scala and I want it to have 2 methods -- add and contains. Also it seems logical to me that a `Set[Cat]` *is* a set of `Set[Animals]` (thus I want it to be declated as `MySet[+A]`).

So I write something like this

```
class MySet[+A] {
    def add[B >: A](elem: B): MySet[B]
}
```

Which seems to be ok until I try to implement `contains` method. In my opinion, the best fitting signature for a method like it should be `def contains(elem: A): Boolean` because a set of `Cat`s can only contain `Cat`s. It can not contain `Dog`s or any other animals.

Of course scala complains about the method like this: `Covariant type A occurs in a contravariant position in type A of value elem` and I even understand why.

My question is how to convince scala that my method `contains` does not mutate my collection in any way and it is safe to pass an element of type `A` into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for **typesafe** `contains`, you can try to create the **typesafe** `implicits` for `contains` to solve `Set`'s `contains` method parameter must be `cotravariant` problem, like:

```
  //implicit bound for `MySet` with the type `A`, so in there `A` is invariant type. 
  implicit class TypeSafeMySetContains[A](s: MySet[A]) {
    def has(a: A): Boolean = s.contains(a) // invoke the `contains` method check
  }
  MySet(1, 2, 3) has "3" // the compiler will throw type mismatch error
  MySet(1, 2, 3) has 3
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that it's either `contains` method in `MySet` accepts `[B <: A]` argument or `MySet` is invariant (`MySet[A]`).

Comment: `MySet` still accepts [B <: A] argument, and for this `implicit` create a **typesafe** `has` method  to do the **type check**. because as your code, `MySet` is **covariant**, and the `contains` method must be `cotravariant`, so this is a way to keep type checking, like the **type equal**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that scala is afraid you are going to mutate the collection.

The problem is that, because your set is covariant, `MySet[Cat]` is a subclass of `MySet[Animal]`. So, if the latter is allowed to have `def contains(a: Animal)`, the former must have one too.

You can make it work with the same trick you did with `.add`:

```
 def contains[B >: A](elem: B): Boolean
```

Note that the immutable `Set` in standard scala library is actually *invariant* in the element type. That is because they wanted it to work as a function `A => Boolean`, that would require it to have an `apply(a: A)` that's essentially the same problem you are talking about.

And give back my nick BTW, this is not cool, man!

Comment: Thanks for clarification, mimic-Dima, but still this (as I've understood) fundamental limitation seems to work strange in this case. It is logical that `Set[Cat] <: Set[Animals]` and it is logical only to ask about cats in a set of cats. Though ye, thanks, I now understand why it doesn't like it.

Comment: You are the mimic, I have been here before you :)
Re. "it is logical to only ask about cats" - it's rather questionable, actually. As you say yourself, `Set[Cat] <: Set[Animal]`, which can also be read as "`Set[Cat]` _is_ a `Set[Animal]`". From that point of view, it doesn't seem to be logical at all to not be able to ask whether a set of animals contains a dog, does it?

Comment: Yes, it does. But still, we already know that the answer is `false` and it seems to be right to allow only `Cat`s for questions like this. Though It does seem like an OOP/theoretical limitation, not just scala

Comment: I mean that I would like it if compiler told me that when I write `cats.contains(dog)` then I clearly do something strange.

Comment: You are missing the point. If you treat `Set[Cat]` as a `Set[Animal]` (and that's the intent you declare, by making it covariant), the compiler has no way of knowing it cannot contain dogs.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Let's just say that I want it to be treated like `Set[Animal]` in some cases but not in the others. And this seems to me impossible in OOP paradigm

Comment: Not `OOP paradigm` per se, but the declaration-site covariance. You can do things like this with use-site covariance (which makes sense, because if you "sometimes" want one thing, and "other times" want another, you have to have a way to differentiate between those cases, which is impossible to do with just a single declaration).

Comment: @Dima Stop talking to yourself, It's weird.